# How to define some variables as non-commutative in Maxima

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

For example, I'd like to define x and y as non-commutative, and a and b as commutative (as usual). In other words,

```
x y ≠ y x,  a x = x a,  a b = b a .
```

Further,

`(x + a y) (x - a y) = x^2 + a (y x - x y) - a^2 y^2` .

What is a code for defining x and y, and a symbol for multiplication (such as `*` and `.` ) ?

Comment: Welcome to S O, Please use {} tool box button to represent code parts. I modified it for you right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with Maxima's commutative `*` and non-commutative `.` products in the way that you want by following the next two steps:

1. Declare the symbols `a` and `b` as scalars:

   `declare([a, b], scalar)$`
2. Enable `dotscrules`:

   `dotscrules: true$`

   This simplifies non-commutative products involving scalars to commutative products (*i.e.*, `a.x` becomes `a*x`).

Now you are ready. For example,

```
expand((a*x + b*y) . (a*x - b*y))
```

returns

```
a*b*y.x - b^2*y^^2 - a*b*x.y + a^2*x^^2
```

(note that `^^` is the non-commutative exponentiation operator).

Comment: I'd like to expand a mixed product such as `(x + a y) (x - a y)`. In that case, `.` or `*` alone did not work. Any ideas ?